# text mining with r library stringdist

Tags: r, stringdist

I have the next algorithm prepared for matching two strings.

```
library(stringdist)

qgrams('perimetrico','perimetrico peri',q=2)

   pe ri tr er im me o  et ic co  p
V1  1  2  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0
V2  2  3  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

As far as Im concerned, this is the formal implementation for counting the number of ocurrencies.

```
stringdist('perimetrico','perimetrico peri', method='qgram', q=2)

5
```

But I am not comfortable with that solution. Thats why I want to count over the first result such as the following way:

```
pe=1
ri=1
tr=1
er=1
im=1
me=1
o=0
et=1
ic=1
co=1
p=0
```

So, the final result would be 9/11 = 82% match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use apply (for each row) to count how many occurrences are 0 and subtract that number from `1`.

```
library(stringdist)
foo <- qgrams('perimetrico','perimetrico peri',q=2)
apply(foo, 1, function(x) 1 - mean(x == 0))

       V1        V2 
0.8181818 1.0000000
```

Or you can round (for `0.82`) and multiply by 100 (for `82` percent)

```
apply(a, 1, function(x) round(1 - mean(x == 0), 2) * 100)

 V1  V2 
 82 100
```

Comment: Could you use `mean(x > 0)` in your function?

Comment: @CPak yes, that would work, but I don't know much about OPs data. What if there's `-1` somewhere.

Comment: @PoGibas, point taken, but I don't see why a `-1` would appear in `qgrams` output

Comment: Nono, the contribution was for @PoGibas. I'm sorry if I misspoke.

Comment: No irony, the code apply(foo, 1, function(x) 1 - mean(x == 0)) helps with the process I am developing